# Error while installing pandas

Tags: python-2.7

I am getting this error while installing pandas in ubuntu....

> tensorflow 1.4.1 requires backports.weakref>=1.0rc1, which is not installed.
>   tensorflow 1.4.1 has requirement tensorflow-tensorboard<0.5.0,>=0.4.0rc1, but you'll have tensorflow-tensorboard 1.5.1 which is incompatible.

What needs to be done?

Answer (score 0):

install the weakref  module only

```
pip install weakref
```